# Laravel : eager loading for hasOne relation returns only one non-related row which is the first row in table

Tags: php, null, laravel-5, eager-loading, with-statement

Laravel : eager loading for hasOne relation returns only one non-related row which is the first row in related table, and all remaining objects has null in the related field.

```
    //VehicleManufacturer class
        class VehicleManufacturer extends Model
        {

            public function description()
            {
                return $this->hasOne('App\DescriptionField','id');

            }
            public function brands()
            {
                return $this->hasMany('App\VehicleBrand');
            }
        }
    //DescriptionField class
        class DescriptionField extends Model
        {
            public function vehicleManufacturer()
            {
                return $this->belongsTo('App\VehicleManufacturer');
            }

            protected $fillable = ['ar','en','fr','nl'];
        }
    // and this code to get vehicleManufacturers
                    $manufacturers=VehicleManufacturer::with(['description'])
                    ->take($request->input("length"))
                    ->skip($request->input("start"))
                    ->get();
var_dump($manufacturers->toArray());
```

And the result is :

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2016-09-04 23:15:01" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2016-09-04 23:15:18" ["description_field_id"]=> int(48) ["description"]=> array(7) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["ar"]=> string(7) "ddddddd" ["en"]=> string(4) "dddd" ["fr"]=> string(2) "dd" ["nl"]=> string(10) "dddddddddd" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2016-09-04 23:05:39" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2016-09-05 23:45:12" } } [1]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> int(2) ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2016-09-04 23:15:34" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2016-09-04 23:15:34" ["description_field_id"]=> int(47) ["description"]=> NULL } }
```

to explain the problem more:

My problem is query returns only one non-related row in property description for first VehicleManufacturer object and for the second VehicleManufacturer object the description property is null.
non-related means that a different DescriptionField object is returned ... not the one associated with VehicleManufacturer object.

note in result in first VehicleManufacturer object the description_field_id is 48 but description property contains DescriptionField object with id 1.And the second returned VehicleManufacturer object the description_field_id is 47 and description property contains null.

Comment: so whats your problem?

Comment: My problem is query returns only one non-related row in property description for first VehicleManufacturer and for the second VehicleManufacturer the description property is null.
none related means that a different DescriptionField object is returned ... not the one associated with VehicleManufacturer object.

note in result the description_field_id is 48 but description property contains DescriptionField object with id 1.